# UIScrollView not scrolling in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to achieve horizontal scrolling in a UITableViewCell.

My hierarchy is:

```
cell
-->UIScrollView
 ---->UIVIew
  ------>labels and buttons
```

On the UIScrollView the leading, trailing, top, and bottom constraints are equal to the superview. On the UIView, the leading, trailing, top, and bottom constraints are equal to the superview and the UIView's center is equal to the superview's center. The UIScrollView and the UIView are set to have equal widths. I have tried changing the UIView constraints to be of the content view but that doesn't work for me. I have also tried lower the priority on the width of the UIView to 250 but that doesn't work either. The reason I am doing this is because when loading the tableview on an ipad pro, part of a button in the cell gets cut off whereas on the iphone is doesn't, assuming because of space reasons. I am setting this up via autolayout in storyboard.

[image: Constraints of UIScrollView and UIView]

Comment: When I run my code both the scrollview's width and the uiview's with stay the same. If I programmatically modify the UIView frame while the table view cell is loading to have a larger width scroll still does not occur.  I also extended the button past the width of the scroll view and that does not enable scrolling either.

Comment: Figured out the problem. One was to add trailing constraints to the last button in my UIView and the second was to set the view.width to the contentlayout width and not the superview width.